# Google Assistant Routine custom commands weird behavior

Tags: google-account, alarm, google-assistant

I'm trying to setup Google Assistant Routine for my wake-up alarm. Whenever I create 2 or more custom commands, they tend to change after saving. I'm trying to add 2 commands: **continue music** and **turn do not disturb off** (both these commands are correct and work fine with Google Assistant). But whenever I press the save button and check them back, one of them changes to the other one. So I'm only getting either **2 do not disturb off** or **2 continue music**.

The question is: am I doing something wrong? Maybe I don't understand something about Google Assistant Routines?

My device is **Xiaomi Mi A1** with latest **Android 9** installed.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same behaviour on Pixel 3 XL. Clearly a bug. A workaround is create a new Google routine containing all the things you want to do, and activate that single routine in the clock app.

Comment: Don't remember this helping me. Gonna check it.